# Combining ScatterPlot using JMathPlot

Tags: java, graph, scatter-plot, jmathplot

```
Plot2DPanel plot = new Plot2DPanel();
Plot2DPanel plot1 = new Plot2DPanel();
plot.addScatterPlot("Error plot", Color.yellow, data1);
plot1.addScatterPlot("Error plot", Color.GREEN, data2);
// put the PlotPanel in a JFrame, as a JPanel
JFrame frame = new JFrame("a plot panel");
frame.setSize(600, 600);
frame.setContentPane(plot);
frame.setContentPane(plot1);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I want to plot 2 scatterplots on the same graph.
I tried to do it by the above code but it is not working. In output I am getting the scatterplot of data2 only.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding both plots to the same `Plot2DPanel`:

```
Plot2DPanel plot = new Plot2DPanel();
plot.addScatterPlot("Error plot", Color.yellow, data1);
plot.addScatterPlot("Error plot", Color.GREEN, data2);
```